# IOS how to display dictionary of arrays in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, tableview

Right now I have declared:

```
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSMutableString* Severity;
NSMutableString* incidentNumber;
NSMutableDictionary *IncidentGetList;
```

I have successfully retrieve out the data from XMLParser, which the data in the log looks like this:

```
Final Feed : (
        {
        code = 80180058;
        Severity = Warning;
    },
        {
        code = 80167359;
        color = red;
    },
        {
        code = 80143253;
        color = green;
    },
        {
        code = 80118575;
        color = blue;
    },
        {
        code = 80114765;
        color = yellow;
    }
)
```

The question is how do I display this two Mutable string within **ONE CELL**. Which means each cell in the table view displays Code : 12345 and color : yellow.

Below is my codes in table view:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [feeds count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

        cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"color"];
             cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"code"];
        return cell;
}
```

Below is screen shot of my storyboard.
[image: storyboard]

Comment: What have you done now? 1 label: code?

Comment: i couldn't display the datas from the dictionary feeds into the table view.

Comment: my dictionary contain two mutable string severity and incident number. i want both strings to display in one cell of the table view

Comment: Now, nothing is displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine both the values into a string and then display. For e.g.:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

     cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Code : %@ , Color : %@",[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"code"],[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"color"] ];
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: I still can't display the things out.

Comment: What is displayed currently in UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Did you check the connection for the delegate and datasource for your UITableView ? As your other methods looks ok.

Comment: how to check the connection? what info you want me to provide you? sry.

Comment: How you have allocated the UITableView ? If you have used storyboard then check if you have assign the datasource and delegate to your viewController . If programatically then check if testTableView.delegate = self; and testTableView.datasource = self; lines are present

Comment: i have assign the datasource and delegate to my viewController.h file.

Comment: where does testTableView.delegate = self  and testTableView.datasource = self;  pasted to? which method do i paste this code in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94883/discussion-between-sneha-and-zac).